# Google Plus didn't accept my email through my friend's invitation

Tags: google-plus

My email is **example.user@gmail.com**. So when I look at my friend's laptop, it shows that the invited email is **exampleuser@gmail.com** (without the period/dot in the username).

What can I do to solve this? Why didn't Google Plus accept my email through my friend's invitation?

Comment: With Google+ now open to all, it seems there is no use for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there's two parts to this - gmail [dosen't actually recognise the period](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) as part of the username, so in essence its the same e mail

the [second is the invite mechanism](https://plus.google.com/107117483540235115863/posts/PhJFJqLyRnm) is down due to overwheming demand

You just have to wait.

Comment: i'd note, the invite mechanism now works sporadically but dosen't send an email.

Answer (score 3):

Options:

1. Use `danaladine@gmail.com`, because `gmail` treats e-mails with or without dots the same.
2. Wait for an invitation on your other mail, or till the site becomes public.
3. See if `Google+` allows you to change your e-mail address after signing up.